# Linux shell syntax

Tags: bash

I have move ksh script to bash. This script have line which I can't understood:

```
 pgp -z <pwd> +force $NAME1
```

Can any one help me to find what  means or what it's role in this line? 
-z option used to pass password into pgp. So possibly  could be variable with password. But string pwd is used only once in this script. Maybe it's just redirect or some global variable?

Comment: this doesn't make sense to shell programmers. Are you saying that the `ksh` code contains the literal string you have quoted, including the `<pwd>`? don't you mean `"$pwd"` ? OR is preceded with the comment character `#`? Good luck.

Comment: in code it's <pwd> It's not "$pwd", and not comment. The same is used in other places for example db login: `user/<pwd>@srv`

Comment: I agree with @Gary_W below, as his answer is the most likely explanation. But does that mean you have never seen the `ksh` version of this code in use? While it may pass syntax checks, it seems it would generate errors. `pgp -z <pwd` does make (some) sense, but the following '> +force` would create a file named `+force` `pgp` would most likely exit with an error. So figure out how you're going t manage your pswds, (a simple solution is `pwd="xyz"`; pg -z "$pwd" ...` which is not a good security thing). . . . .

Comment: Proper security of passwords is a whole different Q, which you should think about before posting your next Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's just a text placeholder for the actual password, meaning "replace me with the actual password when you use this script"  or perhaps: "replace me with the actual password when you use this script, if you don't care about security and don't mind hardcoding your password for all to see".

EDIT:
Is it possible the script was in the middle of being worked on and the developer had not yet figured out a secure way of supplying the passphrase and just used that for a placeholder in the meantime?  I found this interesting description of the -z argument [here](http://linux.feldt.com/meeting_notes/1996/0718/pgp_how.html):

```
Enter pass phrase on command line
pgp -z "you really shouldn't ought to do this"
```

Comment: script is finished, and it's working... I starting to thing, that it's used as string - `<pwd>`. Hours of "googling" don't gives any info.

Comment: @Alchazar - Always start with the man page and study the arguments first. I would have to strongly advise against supplying a hardcoded password for security reasons though.  Not only is it visible in the script, but I believe it's also visible in the process table via the `ps -ef` command.  Look into alternate methods.  as @shelter mentioned, thats a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted person, who wrote these scripts and send them to me. It's not password, it's just text. He replaced passwords in all scripts to <pwd>, and forgot to log this in documentation...